# Formatting issue with Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I am having problems formatting a paper in the correct way. Here's the image where you can see two overlapping sheets. On the left the correct format, on the right the problematic one.

[image: problematic document printout]

edit: every parameter is the same

edit2: link to files on wetransfer https://we.tl/t-cVJwKZCxuN

Comment: Post your document online so we can have a look at it (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Comment: Here's the link to Wetransfer, thank you! https://we.tl/t-cVJwKZCxuN

Comment: I see no difference between the two files as regarding the layout around the title. I'm using Office365.

Comment: Are these printed by the same user on the same printer?

Comment: @harrymc, you should check pag. 2, problems start there

Comment: @Luuklag, yes..